# Missing step: debian-installer-launcher

Tags: debian, system-installation, livecd

I created a Debian Live Image, but I'm missing a step for getting the debian-live-installer to work. I took the following steps:

```
##needed packages
apt-get install --assume-yes xorriso live-build syslinux squashfs-tools

##create basic system
mkdir ~/livework && cd ~/livework
debootstrap --arch=amd64 wheezy chroot

##chroot
cd ~/livework
chroot chroot
mount none -t proc /proc
mount none -t sysfs /sys
mount none -t devpts /dev/pts
export HOME=/root
export LC_ALL=C
export PS1="\e[01;31m(live):\W \$ \e[00m"

##kernel and set password
apt-get install --assume-yes dialog dbus
dbus-uuidgen > /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
apt-get install --assume-yes linux-image-amd64 live-boot
passwd

##install packages
apt-get install --assume-yes xserver-xorg slim fluxbox debian-installer debian-installer-launcher


##finished chroot
apt-get clean
rm /var/lib/dbus/machine-id && rm -rf /tmp/*
umount /proc /sys /dev/pts
exit

##setup isolinux
cd ~/livework
rm chroot/root/.bash_history
mkdir -p binary/live && mkdir -p binary/isolinux
cp chroot/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64 binary/live/vmlinuz
cp chroot/boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64 binary/live/initrd
rm binary/live/filesystem.squashfs
mksquashfs chroot binary/live/filesystem.squashfs -comp xz -e boot
cp /usr/lib/syslinux/isolinux.bin binary/isolinux/.
cp /usr/lib/syslinux/menu.c32 binary/isolinux/.

##sample binary/isolinux/isolinux.cfg
ui menu.c32
prompt 0
menu title CASED Boot Menu
timeout 50

label live-amd64
menu label Live amd64
menu default
linux /live/vmlinuz
append initrd=/live/initrd boot=live persistence quiet

label live-amd64-failsafe
menu label ^Live (amd64 failsafe)
linux /live/vmlinuz
append initrd=/live/initrd boot=live persistence config memtest noapic noapm nodma nomce nolapic nomodeset nosmp nosplash vga=normal

endtext

##build iso
cd ~/livework
xorriso -as mkisofs -r -J -joliet-long -l -cache-inodes -isohybrid-mbr /usr/lib/syslinux/isohdpfx.bin -partition_offset 16 -A "Debian Live"  -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o my-debian.iso binary
```

After Logging into my Live System, I want to be able to install it to my hdd. By executing debian-installer-launcher i get the following error:

```
no suitable d-i initrd image found, aborting
```

I googled for it, but could not find any answer. What step am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, solved it. The following steps did the job:

```
cd ~
## [ get debian-live iso... ]

## create folder for mounting the iso
mkdir debian
mount debian.iso debian/

## copy install (contains initrd(gtk/normal) and vmlinuz)
cp -r debian/install livework/binary/
## copy needed files for installation
cp -r debian/pool livework/binary/
cp -r debian/dists livework/binary/

## create iso
cd ~/livework
xorriso -as mkisofs -r -J -joliet-long -l -cache-inodes -isohybrid-mbr /usr/lib/syslinux/isohdpfx.bin -partition_offset 16 -A "Debian Live"  -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o my-debian.iso binary
```

Hope this might be helpful for somebody else too ;)